# How to display KML files on top of a MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, kml

I have downloaded KMLViewer from  [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html). Its working fine with sample kml provided in this demo but if I am trying to put my kml file in that demo then its not showing few details like polygon with color. It's only displaying pins. PFA screenshot which shows how map is looking right now and how it should look actually

[image]

Comment: Cant use kml files directly with MKMapView:Use NSXMLParser , and parser (probably title, latitude, longitude).